# Website Positions wrong in IE

Tags: css

The website in question is [DCWB](http://www.dcwb.org.uk)

*Forgot to outline problem*

Basically everything looks fine in FF, but when I look at it in IE most of the DIV's are postioned wrong.

*

Could anyone help with this problem please?

```
body {
    background-color:#000;
    font-size:8px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:10px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    color:#FFF;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
#header {
    background-color: #900;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
#apDiv1 {
    visibility:hidden;
    position:fixed;
    width:34px;
    height:114px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 100px;
}
#pic{
    width: 108px;
    right: 10px;
    top: 150px;
    position: fixed;
}
#facebook {
    width: 34px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 100px;
    position: fixed;
}
#Twitter {
    width: 34px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 200px;
    position: fixed;
}
#Menu {
    background-color:#900;
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:12px;

}
#content {
    width:800px;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    left: 50%;
    top:44px;
    margin-left: -400px;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
table tr td #Menu tr td p {
    font-size: 12px;
}
table tr td table tr td strong {
    font-size: 12px;
}
a:link {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
}
a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps if you describe what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many websites that don't look good in ie, this is because it doesn't "obey" to internet standards.  There are many bugs, including the double margin float bug.  This javascript might help you with the problems you may be experiencing:

http://dean.edwards.name/IE7/

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'm thinking i might just build from scratch again and do all my testing IE, then create a seperate CSS Page for FF.

Comment: Wait a sec, you should do your testing in a internet-complaints browser (FF, safari, chrome) then make a separate stylesheet for ie, basically the reverse of what you are saying.

Answer (score 2):

in your code there isn't a [DOCTYPE](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html) declaration and this make the IE to run in [quirks mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/). Add the following in the start of your html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
```

Comment: what do you mean by css page? In your php page (for example index.php) you must add the doctype to run correctly